# Are there any downsides to editing SharedPreferences regularly?

Tags: android, performance

The [example code](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/data/data-storage.html#pref) for [SharedPreferences](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/SharedPreferences.html) on developer.android.com shows the editor being called in the `onStop()` method.

Is this because editing SharedPreferences is resource intensive?
Is it okay to edit SharedPreferences on a function called regularly in the program? Or should changes be kept to local variables and only be called `onStop()`?

Comment: Depends what you mean by "regularly". If it's changed when the user interacts, I'm sure that's fine. If you're trying to use sharedpreferences for updating stock tickers in real time, probably not.

Comment: "Is this because editing SharedPreferences is resource intensive?" -- it involves disk I/O, so it's not especially cheap. Now, if you use `apply()` on your `SharedPreferences.Editor`, that disk I/O is done on a background thread, but that just cuts the jank in your UI. It still consumes CPU and battery.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

sharedprefs are backed by a local file in your `/data/` directory, so yes saving data involves disk I/O which is not cheap. The performance impact might be negligible depending on what you are trying to do though because the saving is done on a background worker thread.

There isn't an answer to this question. You need to run experiments and measure performance across different devices and OSes to gauge what kind of impact this will have.

Comment: Let's not forget that SharedPreferences uses XML to store the data. So serializing would also consume some time and performance

Comment: Good point, depending on the data being stored, serialization should be negligible compared to IO, but good to keep in mind!